Understanding use of cudaGetSymbolAddress in CUDA to copy nested structure
I have a nested data structure which is stored on both host and device. I would like to copy the relevant inner field from host to device. Assume I have done all the allocations correct. Then, I would need the address of the innermost member on the device side (which I am obtaining via a kernel launch) and then storing this address into a dummy variable (which I am doing via cudaGetSymbolAddress) and then performing the copy (through cudaMemcpy). However, it doesn't seem to work. The following is a snippet of the code:
__device__ int* d2;
__global__ void getLIO(EdgeSentinel** d_vd, unsigned int c)
{
    d2 = &(d_vd[c]->last_insert_block->last_insert_offset);
    printf("d2 contains = %p\n", d2);
}

int main()
{   
    // Assume rest of allocations of the structure d_vd (on device) and vd (on host) are done right.
    // Roughly, structure vd contains a field called last_insert_block which is a pointer to another structure which contains a field called last_insert_offset which is an int.
    
    unsigned int c, k;
    // Assume c and k are initialized to some values.
    
    getLIO<<<1,1>>>(d_vd, c);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    int* dummy;
    cudaGetSymbolAddress((void**)&dummy, d2);
    printf("Dummy contains = %p\n", dummy);
    cudaMemcpy(dummy, &(vd[k]->last_insert_block->last_insert_offset), sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
}

In the above snippet, when I print the addresses for debugging, I notice that what d2 contains is not the same as the value contained in dummy. So I am not sure what cudaGetSymbolAddress does at all. How does it work?
I am using this as a workaround, because I cannot directly use cudaMemcpy to copy the nested field from host to device, since this requires me to dereference the structure on the device side, which isn't allowed on the host; i.e.,
cudaMemcpy(&(d_vd[c]->last_insert_block->last_insert_offset), 
           &(vd[k]->last_insert_block->last_insert_offset),
           sizeof(int), 
           cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

won't work since I am dereferencing d_vd which is a device pointer. So if not cudaGetSymbolAddress, what other way is there to achieve this?

Why would the contents of d2 and dummy (which is effectively &d2) ever have the same value?  I wouldn’t expect that code in your question should ever print the same values. cudaGetSymbolAddress does literally what its name says — it returned the address of a symbol in GPU memory. That’s it. I don’t know what you are expecting to happen but the problem isn’t with the API

Side-note: Both host and device can directly read and write memory allocated with cudaMallocHost. This might save you some hassle there. Alternatively this looks like a fine candidate for unified memory

@talonmies: So how do I get the address of d_vd[c]->last_insert_block->last_insert_offset into dummy at all then?

@Homer512: I would like to avoid using UVM. I am trying to understand the limitations of UVM (I wrote an original version which did use UVM).

Use cudaMemcpyFromSymbol if you want the value of d2

You are getting your indirections messed up.
d2 contains the pointer to the the last_insert_offset. cudaGetSymbolAddress gets to the address of d2, meaning the pointer to the pointer. Your host-side code should look like this:
    int* d2_value;
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&d2_value, d2, sizeof(d2));
    cudaMemcpy(d2_value,
               &(vd[k]->last_insert_block->last_insert_offset),
               sizeof(int),
               cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

However, that whole exercise seems rather pointless if you need a kernel to set the current d2 value. You might as well use a kernel to directly set the last_insert_offset value using a value provided in its parameters, right? This seems more useful for getting the last_insert_offset rather than setting it.
